# Converting UNICODE to shiftJIS

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, shift-jis

I have a Japanese client and have generated a large flat file (1.2 million rows) of data to send to them.

The file is UTF-8 encoded, which supports storing and displaying all the Japanese characters. The client wishes to receive this file in a shiftJIS encoded format that's designed for Japanese characters.

1. From the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS#Description) I can get the conversion logic
2. I see online converters such as [motobit](http://www.motobit.com/util/charset-codepage-conversion.asp) that let you convert encodings.

My issue is that my file is quite large and I will have to do this for several hundred more files repetitively. The copy-paste field on the online converter tool won't scale to that size and isn't quick enough.

Does anyone know of a free desktop application or perhaps even a ruby library that I could use to convert encodings? Or any other suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: What system? On most *NIX systems iconv is installed by default: `$ iconv -f UTF-8 -t SJIS file.csv > file.sjis.csv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you want might be the `nkf`, Network Kanji Filter.

You can convert a file from utf-8 into shift-jis like this:

```
% nkf -s file-utf8.txt > file-sjis.txt
```

manual page:
http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/nkf1.html

wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Kanji_Filter

You can install nkf like this:

```
% sudo yum install nkf 
% sudo port install nkf
% brew install nkf
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: There should be no need to install anything, as `recode` or `iconv` should already be installed on any reasonably post-Columbian U*x system.

Comment: I am trying to convert a file in utf-8 to shift-JIS. But it doesn't work as expected. The resulting file has weird characters in it, instead of Japanense ones. All the JP characters are garbled - http://imgur.com/sbibRAT

Comment: converted a file using `nkf -s prt1shift.txt > klklklklklk.txt`, and instead of SHIFT_JIS it got converted into Western(ISO-8859-15) with all the JP characters converted to boxes

Answer (score 1):

No need for any tool or utility, just use the [gedit](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit) to convert your files.
Follows the steps mentioned below:

1. Open your file in gedit which you wish to convert, whatever format it may be in.
2. Copy all the contents of the file and paste in a new gedit document.
3. Now, save the file. In the save dialog thus opened select the character encoding as SHIFT_JIS before saving your file, attached is the screenshot below for this:
   [image]
   Change the line ending if you want to. If you do not see the SHIFT_JIS in the select options, then click on the Add or Remove button which is present just below it.
4. In the dialog thus opened, select the SHIFT_JIS from the available encodings in the left column and then click on the Add button. Once added to the encoding menu, select it and save it.
   [image]

Comment: Downvote: Using a GUI tool where a command-line tool is available is *not* an improvement, and likely to break (or just suck immensely) on large files where a simple command-line tool will process arbitrarily large files a line at a time.